# get locations by grouping with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

good work.

I have a mongoose schema similar to the following

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var stations = new mongoose.Schema({
    //başlık
    title: {
        type: String
    },

    //tam adresi
    address: {
        default:"-",
        type: String
    },

    //ücretlendirme bilgisi
    tariff_information: {
        default:"-",
        type: String
    },

    //soketler
    sockets: {
        type: Array,
        default:[]
    },

    //şarj türü (SADECE AC VEYA DC)
    type: {
        type: String
    },

    //istasyon sahibi
    station_owner: {
        type: String
    },

    //istayon benzersiz kodu
    station_code: {
        default:"-",
        type: String
    },

    //gps koordinatı
    loc: {
        "type": {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point'],
            default: 'Point',
        },
        "coordinates": {
            type: [Number],
            default: [0, 0], //[LONG , LAT]
            required:true
        },
    },
}, { timestamps:true, skipVersioning: { dontVersionMe: true } })

stations.index({loc:"2dsphere"})

module.exports = mongoose.model("stations", stations, "stations");
```

I want to get the data by grouping from here, for example, if there are 1000 locations in 10 km2 area, I want it to return only 1 of them to me.

The reason why I want this is that I have close to 10 million documents in my collection and I'm trying to show it on a map, but it doesn't work at all. Let me reply with a minimum distance of 10km between the locations I want.

I tried using $geoHaystack but it is deprecated. I tried with $geoNear and still couldn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: Your question can be better explained with sample json documents and expected output

Comment: You might pre-calculate the 10km-sized Uber H3 hex for each value, then you could query without the need to calculate